# Open file relative to chromium.exe

Tags: c++, chromium

I have recently build chromium to use in my own c++ application. I managed open Urls such as http:://stackoverflow.com/ or file:///C:/index.html

What i want to do is open html files in the same folder as chromium.exe.
calling something like this: file:://index.html

I could get application path within c++ using system specific calls. but that would be troublesome since all the non-ASCII characters and different encodings.

i hope i made it clear enough.

thank you.

Comment: file:///index.html works when launched via standalone chromium.exe. it seems i have made a small mistake in C++ code.
i suspect it is //// instead of ////// .

Comment: consider this issue resolved. it was my stupidity, not enough escape characters.

Comment: If the issue is resolved, answer to your question and check-mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider this issue resolved. it was my stupidity, not enough escape characters.